# Timing for Android GPS logging is inaccurate

Tags: java, android, gps, android-gps

In my app I am trying to get the users current location and log it. The user can select an interval. Right now the logging is not happening consistently. Sometimes the logs are just off by a couple seconds and sometimes they are off by a few hours. Also if it is not logging and you turn the GPS off/on then it will start working again. The entire app is based around the idea that you will only be able to get your location using GPS when you use it.  I have a few theories as to why this may be.

I am getting the logs by using AlarmManager setExact inside a broadcast receiver. I know that this is not guaranteed to be perfectly accurate and could possible account for a few seconds here and there.

I also know that the GPS can take some time to acquire. Is there a normal range for this time. I could see this taking up to a few minutes possibly but several hours seems like a lot.

I don't know a lot about loopers and am having some difficulty understanding them. I was wondering if the looper in the requestSingleUpdate could have anything to do with it

```
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, Looper.myLooper());
```

I know loopers process tasks in the background using a queue and I was't sure if other tasks could get stuck on the queue in front of it causing delays.

My last theory is that it has something to do with not timing out while searching for the GPS signal. If I am searching for a signal every 10 seconds (the fastest allowed) but the phone cannot find a signal the AlarmManager will fire again and I will have two services trying to get a signal. I don't really understand how the services work under the hood so I don't know if this is a possibility or not.

If anyone has any ideas/resources and could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

Here is the code. I can include more if that would be helpful.

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(SettingsActivity.PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(!pref.getBoolean(SettingsActivity.ARG_TRACK, true)){
        return;
    }

    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

    long interval = pref.getLong(SettingsActivity.ARG_TRACKER_INTERVAL, 15000);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis()+interval, pendingIntent);
    }else{
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    }

    context.startService(new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), AlarmService.class));
}
```

Inside my service I am calling LocationManager requestSingleUpdate()

```
    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, Looper.myLooper());
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my app I am trying to get the users current location and log it. The user can select an interval. Right now the logging is not happening consistently. Sometimes the logs are just off by a couple seconds and sometimes they are off by a few hours. Also if it is not logging and you turn the GPS off/on then it will start working again. The entire app is based around the idea that you will only be able to get your location using GPS when you use it. I have a few theories as to why this may be.

If i'm not wroing, in your scenario, the interval is not period of location provider. It's directly period of alarm. The story like that

- User selects an interval(period), for example 10 minutes.
- After 10 minutes(approximately), device wakes up and makes location request to receive single location.

In that case you are facing the gps provider's lag. So, each time when wake up, you are waiting the gps provider to be warm. This is why the logs aren't consistently.

> I am getting the logs by using AlarmManager setExact inside a broadcast receiver. I know that this is not guaranteed to be perfectly accurate and could possible account for a few seconds here and there.

You are using exact settings for wake up. This is not actual reason of long lag.

> I also know that the GPS can take some time to acquire. Is there a normal range for this time. I could see this taking up to a few minutes possibly but several hours seems like a lot.

You have to wait until GPS provider to be warm. This warming time could change by where you stay at this moment. If you are inside a building, takes long

> I don't know a lot about loopers and am having some difficulty understanding them. I was wondering if the looper in the requestSingleUpdate could have anything to do with it

Simply, when you pass a thread's looper here, onLocationChanged() method will be used the looper. But you are already making single request. No more update will be fired. (In your scenario, each wake up is one single location request)

> My last theory is that it has something to do with not timing out while searching for the GPS signal. If I am searching for a signal every 10 seconds (the fastest allowed) but the phone cannot find a signal the AlarmManager will fire again and I will have two services trying to get a signal. I don't really understand how the services work under the hood so I don't know if this is a possibility or not.

This is a problem of your scenario. If you set alarm with short period, it's so normal the next wake up could happen. You can follow below things

- Due to wait until gps warm, make long alarm period at least 5 minutes
- Make timeout scenario, for example wait 1 minute or more until receiving location.
- If cant receive location in time, shutdown everything and wait the next wakeup.